# how to call python variables inside bash commands in a python script or can I do that?

Tags: python, bash, cron

I am trying to list cronjobs of all users

```
user_file = open('/root/pys/userdomains', 'r')
for line in user_file:
    print line
    splitted_line = line.split(': ')
    print splitted_line
    user_cron = splitted_line[1].split()[0]
    print user_cron
    print "crons for", user_cron, "is", CronTab(user=user_cron)
```

On last line, can I use

```
os.system('crontab -l -u user_cron')
```

to get similar result? I know there is CronTab option, but in similar cases, can I use python variables (e.g. user_cron) inside bash commands.

Comment: `os.system('crontab -l -u %s'%user_cron_variable)` ? is that what you are asking?

Comment: yes, exactly  thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite: you need to construct the actual command string you want to use: Append the string value of **user_cron** to the literal part of the command.

```
os.system('crontab -l -u ' + user_cron)
```

Comment: i think you are missing a trailing space

Comment: Not any more, thanks to you.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use `os.system` function, but you must `import os`.

```
import os
os.system('crontab -l -u user_cron')
```